# Как автоматически прокрутить блок вниз?

Tags: vue.js

Я пишу чат, мне нужно чтобы чат-бокс автоматически прокручивался вниз при появлении новых сообщений.
Вот тот самый чат-бокс

```
<div class="chat-box" id="block">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
                <strong>>>> {{ message.user }}: {{message.text }} ({{message.timestamp}})</strong>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Я создал метод

```
scrollToEnd(){
            var elmnt = document.getElementById("block");
            elmnt.scrollIntoView();
        }
```

Но у меня все равно ничего не работает

Comment: Конечно самостоятельное решение всегда радует сердце, но если никто не ответит держите готовое решение на vue, сыль: https://github.com/theomessin/vue-chat-scroll?ref=madewithvuejs.com

Comment: Оформите минимально воспроизводимый пример в снипет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет работать, если совсем по простому.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      container: null,
      messages: [{
          user: 'name1',
          text: 'value1'
        },
        {
          user: 'name2',
          text: 'value2'
        },
        {
          user: 'name3',
          text: 'value3'
        },
        {
          user: 'name4',
          text: 'value4'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    messages: function(newValue) {
     this.container.scrollTop = this.container.scrollHeight;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.container = document.getElementById("container");
    setInterval(() => {
        this.messages.push({
          user: 'name1',
          text: 'value1'
        });
    }, 250);
    
  },
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="chat-box" id="container">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
        <strong>
          >>> {{ message.user }}: 
          {{message.text }}
        </strong>
      </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```